# jQuery - Get ID of an element and if it equals value then add the link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am currently using the following code to get values from a database and then add the values to a form I have. The first part appends the name of the Firewall and also add's the unique ID to the id for the element.

```
if (value.type == 'Firewall') {
   $('#companyFirewall').append('<div class="detailsFirewall" id="Firewall' + value.id + '">' + value.value + '</div>');
}
```

This next section of the code will get the "thing_id" from the database, which will be a foreign key that relates to to the "Firewall" unique ID, and if it matches the "id" of the element it will wrap the text with the link that is in the database.

```
if (value.type == 'Firewall URL') {
  if ($('.detailsFirewall').attr('id') == 'Firewall' + value.thing_id) {
    $('#Firewall' + value.thing_id).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + value.value + '" />');
  }
}
```

Now, **the problem** I am having is it's only wrapping the first text and doesn't do the rest of them. Right now it is all in one function, but I have tried to put it in function by itself and then call it once the other function has finished. I also tried putting a couple second delay on the function, this didn't work either. What can I do to fix this?

Here is the entire block of code:

```
$.get( submitLink, { business_id: business_id, sitePath: sitePath, companyFirewall: companyFirewall } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data);
    $(results).each(function(key, value) {

        /* Add the data */
        if (value.type == 'Firewall') {
            $('#companyFirewall').append('<div class="detailsFirewall" id="Firewall' + value.id + '">' + value.value + '</div>');
        }
        if (value.type == 'Firewall URL') {
            if ($('.detailsFirewall').attr('id') == 'Firewall' + value.thing_id) {
                $('#Firewall' + value.thing_id).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + value.value + '" />');
            }
        }

        /* Logs the data in the console */
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: I think your use of jQuery is a bit of an overkill and may be actually be keeping you from finding the solution.
Consider changing the code inside `if (value.type == 'Firewall URL')` to something like:

`var el = document.getElementById('Firewall' + value.thing_id);
if (el) {
  $(el).wrap...
}`

Comment: `data` looks like: `{"type":"Firewall","value":"Name","thing_id":null,"id":"1"}`

Comment: `data` for Firewall URL: `{"type":"Firewall URL","value":"http://url.com","thing_id":1,"id":"3"}` _Before Parse_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to evilham his solution fixed my issue.

I changed:

```
if (value.type == 'Firewall URL') {
    if ($('.detailsFirewall').attr('id') == 'Firewall' + value.thing_id) {
        $('#Firewall' + value.thing_id).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + value.value + '" />');
    }
}
```

To this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('Firewall' + value.thing_id); 
    if (el) {
        $(el).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + value.value + '" />');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are looping and appending each `'.detailsFirewall'` class but in the second if block you are not looping and checking each one ..

Example :

**Change :**

```
 if (value.type == 'Firewall URL') {
     if ($('.detailsFirewall').attr('id') == 'Firewall' + value.thing_id) {
         $('#Firewall' + value.thing_id).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + value.value + '" />');
     }
 }
```

**To :**

```
if (value.type == 'Firewall URL') {
    //Will check each detail appended 

    $('.detailsFirewall').each(function(){

        //Now you can reference this to get current element in iteration

     if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Firewall' + value.thing_id) {


         $('#Firewall' + value.thing_id).wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + value.value + '" />');
     }



     })


 }
```

Hope this helps